# handling NA in if_else in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have the following dataset with three columns containing dates.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(45)

df1 <- data.frame(hire_date = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'),    as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="week"), 10),
              t1 = sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2001/01/01'), by="week"), 10),
              t2 = sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2001/01/01'), by="day"), 10))

#this value is actually unknown
df1[10,2] <- NA

    hire_date         t1         t2
1  1999-08-20 2000-05-13 2000-02-17   
2  1999-04-23 2000-11-11 2000-04-27   
3  1999-03-26 2000-04-15 2000-08-01   
4  1999-05-07 2000-06-03 2000-08-29   
5  1999-04-30 2000-05-27 2000-11-19   
6  1999-04-09 2000-12-30 2000-01-26   
7  1999-03-12 2000-12-23 2000-12-07  
8  1999-06-25 2000-02-12 2000-09-26  
9  1999-02-26 2000-05-06 2000-08-23 
10 1999-01-01       <NA> 2000-03-18
```

I'd like to perform an if else statement such that df1$com is 1 if the difference between t1 OR t2 and hire_date is between [395,500]

The following if_else statement almost gets me there, but the NA mucks it up. Any ideas?

```
df1$com <- if_else((df1$t1 - df1$hire_date) >= 395 &
               (df1$t1 - df1$hire_date) <= 500, 1,
       if_else((df1$t2 - df1$hire_date) >= 395 &
                (df1$t2 - df1$hire_date) <= 500, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Maybe add some `& !is.na` statements here and there.

Comment: How the `NA` should be handled?

Comment: Something like this...`df1$com <- if_else(!is.na(df1$t1) & (df1$t1 - df1$hire_date) >= 395 &
                       (df1$t1 - df1$hire_date) <= 500, 1,
                   if_else(!is.na(df1$t2) & (df1$t2 - df1$hire_date) >= 395 &
                               (df1$t2 - df1$hire_date) <= 500, 1, 0))`?

Comment: Yes, I guess I've been staring at it too long to realize that's the obvious solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `dplyr::case_when` instead of nesting the `if_else` statements.  It will give you easy control over how to treat `NA`.  And `dplyr::between` will clean things up as well for your date comparisons.

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(com = case_when(
    is.na(t1) | is.na(t2) ~ 999, # or however you want to treat NA cases
    between(t1 - hire_date, 395, 500) ~ 1,
    between(t2 - hire_date, 395, 500) ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0 # neither range is between 395 and 500
  ))

#>     hire_date         t1         t2 com
#> 1  1999-08-20 2000-05-13 2000-02-17   0
#> 2  1999-04-23 2000-11-11 2000-04-27   0
#> 3  1999-03-26 2000-04-15 2000-08-01   1
#> 4  1999-05-07 2000-06-03 2000-08-29   1
#> 5  1999-04-30 2000-05-27 2000-11-19   0
#> 6  1999-04-09 2000-12-30 2000-01-26   0
#> 7  1999-03-12 2000-12-23 2000-12-07   0
#> 8  1999-06-25 2000-02-12 2000-09-26   1
#> 9  1999-02-26 2000-05-06 2000-08-23   1
#> 10 1999-01-01       <NA> 2000-03-18 999
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: dplyr::between. I've never used case_when and will read up on it.

The issue with your answer is that I don't care whether one or the other is missing, I just want to make sure the difference between either t1 or t2 and hire_date is between 395 and 500. Your code makes df1$com == 999 if either t1 or t2 are missing.

Comment: I see, it was unclear from your post what the desired behavior was with `NA`.  In that case, just delete the first line in my `case_when` command that starts with `is.na(...`

Comment: Deleting 'is.na(...' leaves me where I started. Since t1 is 'NA' it doesn't evaluate t2.

Comment: If I comment out that first line in the `case_when` block above, I get `[1] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1` as the result of the `case_when` - the last value comes from it evaluating t2.  `case_when` does not stop evaluating at `NA`, it looks for a `TRUE` condition.  Compare `if_else(NA, 0, 1)` which gives `NA` to `case_when(NA ~ 0, TRUE ~ 1)` which yields `1`.  When the first `between` statement on t1 evaluates to NA, it progresses to the next line and looks at t2.

Comment: Your response is clear and makes total sense. Unfortunately, when I comment out the first line, I get the following [1]  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1 NA

Comment: ah! I am using the development version of dplyr, 0.5.0.9000 from GitHub.  When I revert to CRAN dplyr 0.5.0, I get the same result as you.  Interesting. If you want the latest version where `case_when` is working inside `mutate()` install with:  `devtools::install_github(c("hadley/dplyr", "krlmlr/bindrcpp"))`.